# Does this look like asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

[image]

Does this look like asbestos to you? It is located in my wash room in the apartment that I am currently living in.

Comment: Once again we fire up the old worldwide inter-tubes  asbestosmeter.  Please  put on your safety glasses,  rubber gloves and respirator and then place your sample under  your computers uplink sensor.    press the energize button and say "I need more power Scotty".  After this fails you will need to  purchase an asbestos testing kit or take your sample to a qualified testing lab  because testing is the only definitive way to know

Comment: For what it's worth (and it's worth nothing ) it just looks like plaster with horse hair in it.

Comment: Horsehair used to be a common additive.

Comment: No, that's not asbestos.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to be sure about asbestos is to have it tested, or to be [capable of looking at the material with a microscope and identifying it](http://www.brunelmicroscopes.co.uk/asbestos.html) (but being **sure** of that identification, positive or negative, generally calls for a lab test.)

A picture can't really identify it, nor rule it out.

But that does look like normal horsehair plaster. Might or might not also have asbestos in it, the stuff got around, so we can't say "it's safe, since it looks like horsehair plaster" since the picture will not show if it's HH plaster without asbestos or with asbestos. But those large fibers are almost certainly horse-hair.